# Header propogration to upstream services

Tags: istio

Is it possible to configure Istio proxy to enrich all of the pod egress traffic with a specific header?

If so, what ways there are to configure the Istio proxy to which header it should propagate?

Comment: If you require more complex logic you can do that with an `EnvoyFilter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this for all pods would require you to use EnvoyFilter and (probably) a simple Lua script. For example:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3 
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: lua-filter
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.filters.http.router"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
       name: envoy.filters.http.lua
       typed_config:
         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua"
         defaultSourceCode:
          inlineString: |
              function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
                  response_handle:logInfo(" ========= XXXXX ========== ")
                  response_handle:headers():add("X-User-Header", "hello")
              end
```

If you're doing this for a one-off pod, you could also use a VirtualService. For example:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: something
  namespace: default
spec:
  hosts:
    - myapp.default.svc.cluster.local
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: myapp.default.svc.cluster.local
          headers:
            response:
              add:
                something: blah
```